# JQuery click event does not trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a project and i use ajax to load content into page.

my jquery function is :

```
function load_room() {
    var sem = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/room_ajax.php?option=2',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'sem': sem },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
            $("#room").html("");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var x = i + 1;
                $("#room").append("<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + data[i]['room_name'] + "<td><a id='edit' href='#'>edit</a></td></tr>");
            };
        }
    });
}
```

The content load success fully but when i click on the `<a id='edit' href='#'>edit</a>` 
element it does not trigger the corresponding click event.
**The code is like:**

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(){
    alert("hai")
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are binding event to element those are present in DOM the time  `on()` is executed. Delegate event to static parent for elements added dynamically.

```
$('#room').on('click', "#edit", function(){
     alert("hai")
});
```

> [Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) have the advantage that they can process events
>   from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later
>   time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the
>   time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated
>   events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event
>   handlers.

Comment: A `,` missing after `"#edit"`. :). Other than that perfect.

Comment: Thank you :) It working now

Answer (score 0):

just note you are clearing the html from #room but then appending trs' and td's

```
         $("#room").html("");

            $("#room").append("<tr><td>...
```

If #room is the div that houses a table, this will cause an issue since you have cleared the table and th structure from the div. Unless #room is the id of the table and you are simply clearing all trs etc from it - but since you did not post the html - I cannae say.

also all of your rows will have an `<a>` with the id of "edit" because you are not differentiating them with each append. Meaning you wikl have multiple ids of "edit" when the table is created with this function.